# how to build docker image that are using java11

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, docker, java-11

I am working with Spring boot. The following Dockerfile and run.sh is working fine and the docker image is built using the docker-plugin in build.gradle.

Now I want to make a docker image of an application that uses some functions of Java11. So, If I made a docker image from the following Dockerfile. How could I do so ? So, that Java11 functions could be accessible with the docker image.

**build.gradle**

```
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
    push = false
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from jar
            into stageDir
        }
        copy {
            from "${project.buildDir}/resources/main/run.sh"
            into stageDir
        }
    }
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8u121-jdk-alpine

# Keep consistent with build.gradle
ENV APP_JAR_NAME pineCharts

# Install curl
RUN apk --update add curl bash && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN mkdir /app

ADD ${APP_JAR_NAME}.jar /app/
ADD run.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/run.sh

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8082

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c"]
CMD ["/app/run.sh"]
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE} -Dgit.config.active.branch=${GIT_BRANCH_LABEL} -Duser.timezone=Asia/Kolkata -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar ${APP_JAR_NAME}.jar
```

Comment: I would start with using base image with java version of 11 instead of 8.

Comment: you mean `FROM openjdk:11` ? and rest of all is same?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest

RUN mkdir -p /software/app

ADD target/app.jar /software/app/app.jar

ENV port=8888

CMD java -jar /software/app/app.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE}
```

Comment: do I need to use `run.sh` ? if i go with your answer?

Comment: No,  my example is without a separate script.

Comment: Facing this error `ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder733948888/target/search.jar: no such file or directory`

Comment: You should run the `docker build` from the root, and make sure there is a target folder with your jar file (ie run mvn package first, then create the image)